# Why does applying an ability handler sometimes fail to absolve the ability requirement?

Tags: unison-lang

With the following code:

```
runGeneration :
  ([BasePair] -> Float)
  -> ([EntityFitness] ->{Random} [EntityFitness])
  -> [EntityFitness]
  ->{Random, Remote} [EntityFitness]
runGeneration = iterateGenDefault 0.8 0.5

bar = Remote.pure.run 'runGeneration
```

UCM shows these signatures:

```
    
    ⍟ These new definitions are ok to `add`:
    
      bar : Either
              Failure
              (([BasePair] -> Float)
              -> ([EntityFitness] ->{Random} [EntityFitness])
              -> [EntityFitness]
              ->{g, Remote, Random} [EntityFitness])
    
    ⍟ These names already exist. You can `update` them to your new definition:
    
      runGeneration : ([BasePair] -> Float)
                      -> ([EntityFitness] ->{Random} [EntityFitness])
                      -> [EntityFitness]
                      ->{Remote, Random} [EntityFitness]
```

The part I'm not understanding is the signature of `bar`, which still has `Remote` in its signature. Shouldn't this be absolved by invoking the handler `Remote.pure.run`?

I have a feeling this is related to my doing something silly, like putting an ability requirement in the wrong place of a signature.

For a simpler example using Random, the `Random` requirement is absolved:

```
randFooH : Nat ->{Random} Nat
randFooH max = Random.natIn 1 max

randFoo max = Random.splitmix 1234 '(randFooH max)
```

```
    ⍟ These new definitions are ok to `add`:
    
      randFoo  : Nat -> Nat
      randFooH : Nat ->{Random} Nat
```

OK, so checking to see if the issue is just with `Remote`, it appears that this is not the case, as this (self-contained) example also absolves:

```
forkHelloH:  '{Remote} Nat
forkHelloH = 'let
  use Nat +
  use Remote await forkAt here!
  t1 = forkAt here! '(1 + 1)
  t2 = forkAt here! '(2 + 2)
  await t1 + await t2

forkHello = Remote.pure.run forkHelloH
```

```
    ⍟ These new definitions are ok to `add`:
    
      forkHello  : Either Failure Nat
      forkHelloH : '{Remote} Nat
```

**Update and clarification**

I was originally trying this partial application of abilities in order to debug an issue - the better way to go about this is (usually) to apply the ability handlers as late as possible. My issue was related to having implemented some functions that weren't ability-polymorphic (see comments in answers below).

Comment: Try putting an explicit type annotation, and you’ll get a type error telling you where the mistake is. I suspect it’s just that you haven’t fully applied runGeneration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing others (hi folks!) + a note about combining those two abilities. I think the reason that `Remote` is showing up in the signature of `bar` is that `runGeneration` isn't being invoked with its arguments.

`runGeneration` is a function which performs the remote ability when it's *applied*, so the signature `bar : Either Failure (([A] -> B) -> ([C] ->{Random} [C]) -> [C] ->{g, Remote, Random} [C])` is saying, "I can either return a Failure or a *function* which happens to perform the Remote ability," but until the calls to the `Remote` ability are actually made, the ability handler can't really eliminate the ability.

Here's a simplified example which allows `bar` to eliminate the `Remote` ability requirement:

```
runGeneration2 : (Nat ->{Random} Nat) -> [Nat] ->{Random, Remote} Nat
runGeneration2 mkNat nats =
  rands = List.map mkNat nats
  List.head rands |> Optional.getOrElse 0

resolveRand :  (Nat ->{Random} Nat) -> [Nat] ->{Remote} Nat
resolveRand mkNat nats = Random.splitmix 243 '(runGeneration2 mkNat nats)

mkNat : Nat -> {Random} Nat
mkNat n =
  Random.natIn 0  n

bar2: Either Failure Nat
bar2 = Remote.pure.run '(resolveRand mkNat [1,2,3])
```

Assuming you may have deferred calling `runGeneration` with its arguments because of the `Random` ability requirement, here's a tip on some complexity there:
because we're performing the `Random` ability in concert with `Remote` there's an order of operations for eliminating abilities.

The signature for the `Remote.pure.run` handler is: `'{Remote, Exception, Scratch} a -> Either Failure a` which has less ability variables than a common ability handler like `Stream.toList : '{g, Stream a} r -> '{g} [a]`. The lack of the generic ability variable `{g}` means `pure.run` can handle the three ability requirements indicated, but does not permit other abilities to be passed through and performed (for safety reasons,) so you'll want to eliminate your `Random` ability before trying to interpret it with the `pure.run` handler.

Comment: Very helpful! A related question - it may actually be preferable to supply all the ability handlers at once; my understanding is that there can only be one handler for each ability in play at a time, so I don't see why they couldn't all be supplied together "at the end". I guess this may be more suitable as another question, though.

Comment: More context: I was actually trying to supply all the handlers at once, but was running into an issue. You jogged my memory in your discussion of the polymorphic ability `g`. I realized some of my dependent functions needed to be polymorphic in the right locations, and this seems to have gotten me much further.  Will update tomorrow in some capacity. Thanks again!

Comment: And as a final follow up on that issue - all my problems were resolved by making relevant functions ability-polymorphic where they needed to be.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because the function that requires the `Remote` ability is not actually being evaluated/handled. The handler only eliminates abilities at the top node of the expression passed to it.

To eliminate it you would need to transform the inner function explicitly by wrapping it in something that applies the handler (?)